# React js drag and drop Image with preview

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have this function for set my variable image and preview image:

```
const handleChangeImage = event => { 
    setPreviewImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    setImage( event.target.files[0] )
}
```

and this one I just get the icon for dag and drop image:

```
<Box                                         
    backgroundColor="gray"      
    onChange={handleChangeImage}                                   
>                               
    <PhotoOutlinedIcon 
        size="large"                                           
    />
    <Box>
        <LabelImage>
            Drag and Drop your Image Here
        </LabelImage>    
        <input 
            type="file"
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            onChange={handleChangeImage}
            ref={hiddenFileInput}       
        />                                            
    </Box>
</Box>


<Box>                                   
    <img 
        src={previewImage} 
        alt="Name Image" 
        width={150}
    />                                          
</Box>
```

so, I just want to do a Drag and drop image with preview, so currently it not work.

I was testing removing of input, the style display and I drag and drop one image, and preview image work, but I just want is display one icon, like:

[image]

so why don't work??? when I add `display: 'none'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a state to store the preview image

```js
const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState(null)
```

Define the handleDragOver and the handleDrop function to handle image drop events.

```js
// Function to prevent default behavior for drag over
const handleDragOver = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
}

// Function to handle image drop
const handleDrop = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const file = event.dataTransfer.files[0]
  if (file) {
    setPreviewImage(URL.createObjectURL(file))
  }
}
```

Create the openFileInput function to trigger a click on the hidden file input when the container is clicked.

```js
const openFileInput = () => {
  hiddenFileInput.current.click()
}
```

Then add conditianlly rendering,

```js
<Box
  ... some styles
  onDragOver={handleDragOver}
  onDrop={handleDrop}
  onClick={openFileInput}
/>
   {previewImage ? (
    <img src={previewImage}/>
  ) : // or render other elements here
</Box>
```